# Mockserver does not catch my requests

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to use http://www.mock-server.com/ to mock a REST service. My source code is trying to make a GET on: http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id

I would like to mock this service. I have currently written in my code:

```
mockServer = startClientAndServer(1080);
proxy = startClientAndProxy(1090);

new MockServerClient("127.0.0.1", 1080)
        .when(
                request()
                        .withMethod("GET")
                        .withPath("/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id"),
                exactly(1)
        )
        .respond(
                response()
                        .withStatusCode(200)
                        .withBody("the_project_id")
        );
```

When I run the mock server client and I then the source code which makes the request, I am still getting a socket exception instead of the reply of the mock server. How can I fix my code to mock http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id? I have fully read the mock-server documentation but I do not understand it very well.

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: Does your personal firewall allow the required connection?

Comment: http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id is unavailable on my dev machine. I am trying to mock it.

Comment: The exception is : java.net.UnknownHostException: metadata.google.internal

Comment: I don't know mock-server, but apparently you'd have to re-configure your code to call `127.0.0.1` instead of `metadata.google.internal` when running tests so that it connects to your local mock server and does not try to connect to the internet server.

Comment: It makes sense. I though it was magically catching all the http requests of my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82966/discussion-between-poiuytrez-and-hanno-binder).